# Having issues moduling zootopia style fur

Tags: particles, hair

Ive heard that Blender was capable of producing Zootopia style fur on characters using the participial system. Well sadly there doesn't seem to be many guides on fur. The few ive found use a ball or a flat plane to show how it works but don't apply it to an actual character

This head I made incapacitates all of my issues

1. I set a vertex group for every part of the head I wanted to add fur to and left out parts like the nose eyes mouth and inner ear yet when I add children it bleeds over into those parts. Ive tried combing the strans as far away as possible and cutting the parent hairs around the bald areas but they just keep bleeding over.

[image: Zootopia Style Fur]

2. I don't know whether or not to use more parent hairs with a hand full of children or very few parent hairs and populate the area with mostly children
3. You can see the hairs clipping though the normal's for two sided areas like the ears

[image: zootopia style fur]

4. The hairs look like these gross cone shapes when viewed closely
5. How can I make sure the fur is distributed evenly across the head? There are these weird random bald spots.

[image]

Comment: I think your model is perfect for Halloween

Answer (score 3):

I am kind of where you are right now. I can give you some input maybe.

1. There might be a better way but a workaround at least is to duplicate the parts of the mesh and then separate them into a new object. That way you won't get hair in areas you don't want it. You can hide the emitter, so you only see the hair.
2. It will probably look better if you use more parents and less children.
3. Might be okay if you do it like answer 1.
4. You can set the thickness of the hair at the root and the tip. Yours is probably still set to 1 at the root. Try lowering it to 0.25
5. I am not sure, maybe related to question 2.

Comment: Sadly if I separated every individual part like that it would be a nightmare to rig and animate

Comment: @Sic You can just parent the parts to the main mesh, so they will move along with it.

Comment: Depending on the mesh, you may be able to use the surface deform modifier to make the hair emitters follow the character closely.

Answer (score 2):

Hairs clipping through is most probably due to the fact that there isn't enough parent hairs:

In Particle Edit mode you can see how adding more parent hairs will make the bald spots go away:

[image]

[image]

But yeah, I tried to do some density and length weight painting tests but they turned out crap. I dunno, I'm not best in hair stuff :/